# Why Using Pointer Like This Is Crashing The Build?

Tags: c, pointers, crash, codeblocks

I am deep diving into pointers in C but when i write a simple code to play around this happens.

[image: Screenshot]

IDE : Code::Blocks

OS: Windows 8.1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;
    x = 6;
    int* p;
    *p = &x; // This is wrong

    printf("%d\n",*p);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? @Pablo told you what's wrong with the code, but perhaps you want to know why this is happening?

Comment: I cannot see the pic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `*p = &x;`. Use `p = &x;` instead.

It's crashing because you are using `*p` on an uninitialized pointer. When you declare `int* p;`, the initialization value of `p` is undefined by the **C Language** specifications. You are also trying to assign an address (`&x`) to an `int` placeholder (`*p`, the value pointed by `p`).

So, when you try to de-reference the `p` pointer on the next sentence by doing `*p`, you are probably trying to access a memory location not available to your process.

```
p = &x; // you are pointing p to x variable memory location
printf("%d\n",*p); // should print 6
*p = 10;
printf("%d\n",*p); // should print 10
printf("%d\n",x);  // should also print 10
```

Comment: Oh my god ! I was de-referencing and re assigning an uninitialized pointer in the same line. Am i really such a dumb. This was very silly.

Comment: This is actually a **wild pointer** situation. A wild pointer is pointer which is declared but NOT initialized so, they point to any random memory location. To know more about wild pointer check out [this video](https://youtu.be/NMxqA8OG2gE)